# I need help building an anchor <a that passes variables to PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently using javascript but switching to jQuery is OK.

Within the HTML is a `<div id="domain">nares</div>`. I need to pick out the "nares" and put it in an anchor tag to look like this: `<a href=myCode.php?domain=nares" rel="modal:open">Listing</a>`.

So far the code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var dom = document.getElementById('domain').innerHTML; 
 openPage = function() {
 location.href = "myCode.php?domain="+dom;
}
</script>

<a href ="javascript:openPage()" rel="modal:open">Link  </a>
```

To me this looks like it should work but instead when the page opens I get;

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating
>   'document.getElementById('domain').innerHTML')

This is probably because the div has not yet been populated. However after population the error changes to:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load javascript:openPage(). Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for HTTP.

Which truthfully I don't understand. In any case using jQuery or just plain javascript how do I build this tag? I really need the modal part to work, its part of the UI for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your `dom` element into the function like so:

```
<a id="test" onclick="openPage()" rel="modal:open">Link  </a>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function openPage() {
      var dom = document.getElementById('domain').innerHTML; 
      document.getElementById("test").href = "myCode.php?domain="+dom;
   }
</script>
```

Also you should get your `a` tag then change the `href`...